# Getting an exception in zend frame work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'abc' in 'where clause'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:234 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1509): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1371): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\application\models\ClmsRegistrationModel.php(116): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchRow('abc') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\application\modules\default\controllers\AuthController.php(65): clms in C:\xampp\htdocs\CLMS\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234
```

What is this exception?
and how it can be solved.

```
public static function setRole($emp_id,$role)
    {
        //$select = $this->select();
        $row = $this->fetchRow('employee_id=?',$emp_id);
        $row->role_organization=$role;
        $row->save();
```

}

Comment: Could you post the statement you are trying to execute? It looks like you are referencing a non-existing column in a where clause.

Comment: public static function setRole($emp_id,$role)
    {
     //$select = $this->select();
     $row = $this->fetchRow('employee_id=?',$emp_id);
     $row->role_organization=$role;
     $row->save();
    }

Comment: Side note: Referencing `$this` in a static method probably warrants some reconsideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception shows that you are calling `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchRow('abc')` from `ClmsRegistrationModel.php` on line 116. That is where the where clause is getting set to 'abc'.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. Can you post what is in `ClmsRegistrationModel.php` around line 116?